# Place items in the same row in Bootstrap

Tags: django, forms, bootstrap-5

I have a problem with the following code. There are two forms after each other: searchform and booksform. I want to put the searchform and the first button of the booksform in the same row with Bootstrap.

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
{% load static %}
<section class="bg-light px-5 py-4">
    
        
        <div class="row mb-4">
            <div class="col-6"><h2 class="h2">Könyvek</h2></div>
            
        </div>

            <form id="searchform" onSubmit="return false;">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchbar"></div>
                <div class="col-2"><input type="button" value="Keresés" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="search"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <form action="{% url 'books' %}" method="post" id="booksform" name="booksform">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-7 text-end"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-3" value="Mentés" id="save" name="save"></div>
        
        <table class="table table-light table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th>Angol cím</th>
                <th>Magyar cím</th>
                <th class="text-center">Olvastam</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
                {% for i in books %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{i.eng_title}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.title}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="check-{{i.id}}" id="check-{{i.id}}" class="form-check-input"></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="checked" id="checked">
    </form>
</section>
<script src="{% static 'js/books.js' %}" defer data-tocheck="{{books_read}}" data-books="{{booksjson}}"></script>
{% include "footer.html" %}
```

I tried to put `<div class="row>` before the searchform and `</div>` after the save button in booksform. It didn't work because I opened the div before the booksform and I closed it inside of that.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think with these adjustements you can get you desired output, just test it and let me know if it works for you:

```html
{% include 'header.html' %}
{% load static %}
<section class="bg-light px-5 py-4">
    <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col-6"><h2 class="h2">Könyvek</h2></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form id="searchform" onSubmit="return false;">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchbar">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <input type="button" value="Keresés" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="search">
            </div>
        </form>
        <form action="{% url 'books' %}" method="post" id="booksform" name="booksform" class="col-7">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="text-end mb-3">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-3" value="Mentés" id="save" name="save">
            </div>
            <table class="table table-light table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>Angol cím</th>
                    <th>Magyar cím</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Olvastam</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">
                    {% for i in books %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{i.eng_title}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.title}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="check-{{i.id}}" id="check-{{i.id}}" class="form-check-input"></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="checked" id="checked">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="{% static 'js/books.js' %}" defer data-tocheck="{{books_read}}" data-books="{{booksjson}}"></script>
{% include "footer.html" %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work.